# Colour coded bootstrap likert scale

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Similar to the button toolbar, I'm trying to implement a colour coded likert scale in my view (I'm using ASP.net) with labels on either side.

"not dangerous" [1][2][3][4][5] "dangerous"

[dark green][light green][yellow][orange][red]

https://gyazo.com/da61f52bae9336c34a9f89d69db5f5d4

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 part answer:

1. Likert - use a disabled `.btn-link` either side

```
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Safe</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
        <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Dangerous</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

2. Color - just override the '.btn' colouring:

```
    .btn.likert-1 { background-color: darkgreen; color: yellow; }
    .btn.likert-2 { background-color: lightgreen; color: brown; }
    .btn.likert-3 { background-color: yellow; color: brown; }
    .btn.likert-4 { background-color: orange; color: white; }
    .btn.likert-5 { background-color: red; color: white; }
    /* Choose better colors tho! */
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taxvkvu9/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm trying to alert() the user with the user's selection by using something similar to $(".btn btn-default").click(function () {})  however it does not seem to be working. What am I missing?